# Keep a log of merges

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, merged-questions

Merges (of tags, users or questions) are, if not impossible to undo, then at least very hard, and requiring developer intervention.

Please keep a log of merges, at least tag merges, in some easily-exploitable form. Bad tag merges (where the tags weren't quite synonyms after all) happen now and then, and having a list of retagged questions would be a great help.

I don't see any issue with making tag merge logs public (buried somewhere in the UI, presumably in the synonym dashboard). User merges, if logged, would of course need to be kept under wraps.

Comment: Better yet, wrap each tag merge in a transaction and put the transactions in a log, so that they can be undone.

Comment: This already exists under the covers as part of a user's history. There have been some... accidents... and so it was put in place. Having said that, it's really not in an easily-consumable state (from a data perspective). I suspect it's visible to developers, though.

Comment: @JonSeigel I've been told this was recently done in a partial form for users, and accessible only by devs. I know of no such log for tags.